# Extract specific cells from multiple csv files and copy them into a new excel file

Tags: r

I need to extract cells from the range C6:E6 (in the code range is [4, 3:5]) from three different csv files ("Multi_year_summary.csv") which are in different folders and then copy them into a new excel files. All csv files have the same name (written above). I tried as follow:

```
library("xlsx")

zz <- dir("C:/Users/feder/Documents/Simulations_DNDC")

aa <- list.files("C:/Users/feder/Documents/Simulations_DNDC/Try_1", pattern = "Multi_year_summary.csv", 
                 full.names = T, recursive = T, include.dirs = T)
bb <- lapply(aa, read.csv2, sep = ",", header = F)

for (i in 1:length(bb)) {
  xx <- bb[[i]][4, 3:5]
  qq <- rbind(xx)
  jj <- write.xlsx(qq, "C:/Users/feder/Documents/Simulations_DNDC/Try_1/Results.xlsx",
                   sheetName="Tabelle1",col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
}
```

The code is executed, but extracts the cells only from one file so that in Results.xlsx I have only one row instead of three. Maybe the problem starts from `xx <- bb[[i]][4, 3:5]` since if I execute `xx` the console gives back "1 obs. of 3 variables" instead of 3 objects.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the csv you can extract the relevant data needed in the same `lapply` loop, combine them into one dataframe and write it in xlsx format.

```
result <- do.call(rbind, lapply(aa, function(x) read.csv(x, header = FALSE)[4, 3:5]))

write.xlsx(result, 
          "C:/Users/feder/Documents/Simulations_DNDC/Try_1/Results.xlsx",
           sheetName="Tabelle1",col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```